# Automatically delete google sheet rows if older than 24 hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Automatically delete google sheet rows if older than 24 hours
I wants to write this code in Google Apps Script

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092901/google-sheets-clear-all-rows-with-a-date-cell-having-a-date-older-than-one-wee   or  have a formula that zeroes out the row based on the current time

Comment: You can workaround without using scripts. You need timestamp for each row anyway to determine if it's older than 24hours. If you want only newer rows, you can use filter function and filter only newer posts (in new sheet). This way you still have an archive of older rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
function dro() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=2;//data starts here
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());//assume first column is date
  let v=rg.getValues();
  let d=0;
  let dtv=new Date().valueOf();
  v.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if((dtv-new Date(r[0]).valueOf())/3600000>24) {
      sh.deleteRow(sr+i-d++);
    }
  });
}
```